# Return statement function in if conodition

Tags: java, if-statement, return

In my code:

```
if (id.isEmpty() || name.isEmpty()) {
    warlbl.setText("Warning, Empty ID or Name Fields");
    return;
}
```

`id` and `name` are `String` that give from `JTextFields` ,

Is necessary use `return;` in here or Not?

Comment: `return` causes the method to return.  Do you need the method to return?  If so, then use `return`.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do but is it stands its perfectly fine to do so.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I think that, in my code, `return` causes to check again the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**return** exits the current method you are "in".

Of yource it is not necessary but maybe you want to exit the method if **id.isEmpty()** and **name.isEmpty()**. So no and yes. It is not neccassary but you may want to **return**

You can use return to break out of a method, continue to skip a loop or a break to break out of a block.

Often there are 2 ways:

```
public void test() {
    if (!statement) {
       // to something if statement is false
    } else {
       //we failed, maybe print error 
    }
}
```

or:

```
public void test() {
    if (statement) {
       //we failed, maybe print error 
       return;
    }

    //do something if statment is false
}
```

But this is more a kind of "style". Mostly I prefere the second way, just because it's less spagetti :P

Keep in mind. If your return statement would be the last statment executed it's redundant.

Java reference:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: I think that, in your second way, `return` causes to check condition again, Correct?

Comment: It's checked in both examples only once. The only difference is the style in this example. Maybe you are more familiar with the first example :D

Comment: But what exactly do you mean with checking again. return just causes "to break out of the method"

Comment: Yes, understand now, Thus in your second way, when `return` executed, `//do something` will be execute, Correct?

Comment: Not exactly when return is reached, we stop executing the method. So //do something  won't execute anymore

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it can be:

```
if (...) {
    ...
    return;
}

// nothing at this point will be reached if the if-statement is entered
```

vs.

```
if (...) {
    ...
}

// code here will still be reached!
```